# Error in Squeeze Theorem Argument

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I am trying to write a proof using the squeeze theorem that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$. My argument must be flawed because I keep coming up with $0$. The argument is as follows.

We first consider $x > 0$, i.e., the limit as $x \to 0^{+}$. We have
$$-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$$
Inverting and reversing inequality signs, we find
$$1 \leq \frac{1}{\sin x} \leq -1.$$
Multiplying through by $x > 0$, which doesn't reserve the inequality signs, we get
$$x \leq \frac{x}{\sin x} \leq -x. $$
Taking $x \to 0^{+}$, the squeeze theorem then implies that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{x}{\sin x} = 0$, which is false. The argument for taking $x \to 0^{-}$ is similar, but for the fact that the inequality signs are reversed.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was true that$$1\leqslant\frac1{\sin x}\leqslant-1,$$then we would have $1\leqslant-1$, which is clearly false.

In fact, from $-1\leqslant\sin x\leqslant1$, what we can deduce (unless $\sin x=0$) is that$$\frac1{\sin x}\geqslant1\quad\text{or}\quad\frac1{\sin x}\leqslant-1.$$

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Is it true in general that I can't invert every element in an inequality chain? The switch to "or" here from the "and" in the statement $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$ is not completely clear to me. Maybe the reason is that the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is not monotonically increasing, so there's no reason the inequality chain should be maintained.

Comment: When $\sin x\ne0$, yu have two possibilities: either $\sin x>0$ or $\sin x<0$. If $\sin x>0$, then $\sin x\leqslant1\implies\frac1{\sin x}\geqslant 1$. And if $\sin x<0$, then $-1\leqslant\sin x\implies\frac1{\sin x}\leqslant-1$.